# resultado: imprimir valor de variável JS em <td>

Tags: javascript, lógica, tabela-html

Estou desenvolvendo um código em que o usuário insere o valor a ser sacado, no resultado é apresentado a quantidade de cédulas de cada valor que será liberado na operação.

Pois bem, a lógica já está pronta. Só estou com dificuldade para exibir o resultado dentro de uma tabela 'pré'-pronta. Ela vem com a referência, tipo: Cédulas de R$ 50,00   e preciso exibir o resultado da variável na linha da frente;

Eu realmente não tenho ideia de como fazer isso, por meio de uma função?

Segue código:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Valor do saque
   </label>  
   <div class="col-md-2">
      <input id="textinput" name="textinput" value="" type="number" placeholder="R$ 00,00" class="form-control input-md" required=true>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="button1id">
   </label>
   <div class="col-md-8">
      <button id="button1id" value="Enviar"  name="button1id" class="btn btn-success" onClick="Enviar()">Confirmar
      </button>
      <button id="button2id" name="button2id" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <table class="table table-striped" id="table_result">
      <tr>
         <th> Cédulas disponíveis </th>
         <th> Quantidade por cédula </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> Cédulas de R$ 50,00 </td>
         <td> aqui deve ser exibido o valor da varíavel n50 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> Cédulas de R$ 20,00 </td>
         <td> aqui deve ser exibido o valor da varíavel n20 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> Cédulas de R$ 5,00 </td>
         <td> aqui deve ser exibido o valor da varíavel n5 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> Cédulas de R$ 1,00 </td>
         <td> aqui deve ser exibido o valor da varíavel n1 </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
   <script language="JavaScript">
    function Enviar() {

        var n50, n20, n5, n1, valor, restv, qtd_n, valor_i;

        n50 = 0;
        n20 = 0;
        n5 = 0;
        n1 = 0;
        valor = 0;
        restv = 0;
        qtd_n = 0;
        valor_i = 0;

        valor_i = document.getElementById('textinput').value;
        valor = valor_i;

        console.log(valor_i)

        if (valor <= 0) {

            window.alert("Atenção: digite um valor acima de R$ 00,00!");

        } else {

            while (valor > 0)

            {

                if (valor >= 50) {

                    n50 = parseInt(valor / 50);
                    restv = (valor % 50);
                } else if (valor >= 20 && valor < 50) {

                    n20 = parseInt(valor / 20);
                    restv = (valor % 20);

                } else if (valor >= 5 && valor < 20) {

                    n5 = parseInt(valor / 5);
                    restv = (valor % 5);

                } else if (valor >= 1 && valor < 5) {

                    n1 = parseInt(valor / 1);
                    restv = (valor % 1);
                }

                valor = restv;


            };

            document.write("O valor a ser sacado é: R$ ", valor_i, "<br/> Distribuído da seguinte forma: <br/>", n50, " notas de        R$ 50,00 <br/>", n20, " notas de R$ 20,00<br/>", n5, " notas de R$ 5,00 <br/>", n1, " notas de R$ 1,00");

        };

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Um jeito simples seria colocar um id nos `td` que receberão o valor, e depois atribuir usando o `innerHTML`, assim:

```js
function Enviar() {

  var n50, n20, n5, n1, valor, restv, qtd_n, valor_i;

  n50=0;
  n20=0;
  n5=0;
  n1=0;
  valor=0;
  restv=0;
  qtd_n=0;
  valor_i=0;

  valor_i=document.getElementById('textinput').value;
  valor=valor_i;

  console.log(valor_i)

  if  (valor <= 0) {

    window.alert("Atenção: digite um valor acima de R$ 00,00!");

  }   else {

    while (valor>0) 

    {

      if (valor>=50) {

        n50=parseInt(valor/50);
        restv=(valor%50);
      } 
      else if (valor>=20 && valor< 50) {

        n20=parseInt(valor/20);
        restv=(valor%20);

      } 
      else if (valor>=5 && valor<20) {

        n5=parseInt(valor/5);
        restv=(valor%5);

      }
      else if (valor>= 1 && valor<5) {

        n1=parseInt(valor/1);
        restv=(valor%1);
      }

      valor=restv;


    }; 
    
    td50.innerHTML = n50;
    td20.innerHTML = n20;
    td5.innerHTML = n5;
    td1.innerHTML = n1;

  };

}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Valor do saque
  </label>  
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <input id="textinput" name="textinput" value="" type="number" placeholder="R$ 00,00" class="form-control input-md" required=true>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="button1id">
  </label>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <button id="button1id" value="Enviar"  name="button1id" class="btn btn-success" onClick="Enviar()">Confirmar
    </button>
    <button id="button2id" name="button2id" class="btn btn-danger">Cancelar
    </button>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container"> 
  <table class="table table-striped" id="table_result">

    <tr>
      <th> Cédulas disponíveis </th>
      <th> Quantidade por cédula </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Cédulas de R$ 50,00 </td>
      <td id="td50"> aqui deve ser exibido o valor da varíavel n50 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Cédulas de R$ 20,00 </td>
      <td id="td20"> aqui deve ser exibido o valor da varíavel n20 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Cédulas de R$ 5,00 </td>
      <td id="td5"> aqui deve ser exibido o valor da varíavel n5 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Cédulas de R$ 1,00 </td>
      <td id="td1"> aqui deve ser exibido o valor da varíavel n1 </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```